# Is there an R function where I can get the names within a specific column in my dataset

Tags: r

Edit: using the aid from one of the users, I was able to use "table(ArrestData$CHARGE)", yet, since there are over 2400 entries, many of the entries are being omitted. I am looking for the top 5 charges, is there code for this? Additionally, I am looking at a particular council district (which is another variable titled "CITY_COUNCIL_DIST"). I want to see which are the top 5 charges given out within a specific council district. Is there code for this?

Thanks for the help!

Original post follows

---

Just like how I can use "names(MyData)" to see the names of my variables, I am wondering if I can use a code to see the names/responses/data points of a specific column.

In other words, I am attempting to see the names in my rows for a specific column of data. I would like to see what names are cumulatively being used.

After I find this, I would like to know how many times each name within the rows is being used, whether thats numeric or percentage. After this, I would like to see how many times each name within the rows is being used with the condition that it meets a numeric value of another column/variable.

Apologies if this, in any way, is confusing.

To go further in depth, I am playing around with the Los Angeles Police Data that I got via the Office of the Mayor's website. From 2017-2018, I am attempting to see what charges and the amount of each specific charge were given out in Council District 5. CHARGE and CITY_COUNCIL_DIST are the two variables I am looking at.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: ChrisIsCool but Chris should add sample data to the post with `dput(head(df,n))`. Chris should also show current and expected output.

Comment: hi, how would I be able to do this? Apologies, I am new to this. @NelsonGon

Comment: You can do it in your R editor/console. Replace `df` in the above line with the name of your dataset or a sample that can best represent your data. Then choose n to decide the number of rows sufficient for reproducibility.

Comment: So, I did this with R Console, how would l be able to share it with you? Additionally, even w/ 20 rows, I can not scroll much. Should I reduce it to, perhaps, 10?

Comment: I also made an edit to the original post considering the aid I received from another user.

Comment: Write your code in a script? The result of `dput` just gives the structure of the data set. If your data set is too large, you can create a very simple but ideally similar to your own data set and use that to pose your question.

Answer (score 1):

To get all the distinct variables, you can use the `unique` function, as in:

```
> x <- c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6)
> unique(x)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

To count the number of distinct values you can use `table`, as in:

```
> x <- c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6)
> table(x)
x
1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 1 2 1 3 1
```

The first row gives you the distinct values and the second row the counts for each of them.

**EDIT**

This edit is aimed to answer your second question following with my previous example.

In order to look for the **top five most repeated values** of a variable we can use base `R`. To do so, I would first create a dataframe from your table of frequencies:

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(x))
```

Having this, now you just have to order the column `Freq` in descending order:

```
df[order(-df$Freq),]
```

In order to look for the **top five most repeated values of a variable within a group**, however, we need to go beyond base `R`. I would use `dplyr` to create an augmented dataframe with frequencies for each value of the variable of interest, let it be `count_variable`:

```
library(dplyr)
x_or <- x %>% 
  group_by(group_variable, count_variable) %>% 
  summarise(freq=n())
```

where `x` is your original dataframe, `group_variable` is the variable for your groups and `count_variable` is the variable you want to count. Now, you just have to order the object in a way you get the frequencies of your `count_variable` ordered by `group_variables`:

```
x_or %>% 
  arrange(group_variable, count_variable, freq)
```

Comment: So, I just tried what you provided through the second part of your answer via "table(ArrestData$CHARGE)", yet, since there are over 2400 entries, many of the entries are being omitted. I am looking for the top 5 charges, do you know how to find them? Additionally, I am looking at a particular council district (which is another variable titled "CITY_COUNCIL_DIST"). I want to see which are the top 5 charges given out within a specific council district. Do you happen to know the code for that?

Comment: I edited my first answer trying to incorporate your new questions.